# How to add new column and get the data from other column? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

You can see what I exactly mean on the image below. 
I want to create new column "**Bill To This Company**"  and get the company name from **BillToCustomerID**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you need  a self join

```
select a.customerId, a.CustomerName, a.BillToCustomerId, b.CustmerName 
from my_table a 
inner join my_table  b on a.BillToCustomerId = b.customerId
```

Answer (score 1):

Just self-join on the table and give that CustomerName an alias

```
select 
 c.CustomerId, 
 c.CustomerName, 
 c.BillToCustomerId, 
 b.CustomerName as "Bill To This Company"
from Customer c
left join Customer b on (b.CustomerId = c.BillToCustomerId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need `subquery` :

```
select c.*,
       (select c1.CustomerName
        from Customer c1
        where c1.BillToCustomerId = c.BillToCustomerId
        order by c1.customerid 
        limit 1
       ) as BilltoThisCompany
from Customer c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableName as t1 join tableName as t2 on t1.BillToCustomerID=t2.CustomerId
  set t1.`Bill To This Company` = t2.customerName;
```